# Out of Sync cdk stacks

Tags: deployment, stack, aws-cdk, aws-parameter-store

I am searching for a solution to avoid an OUT OF SYNC issue between 2 stacks.

Stack B is exposing a value from Parameter Store created through Stack A.

When I delete and recreate the stack A --> The value in Parameter Store will be changed, but Stack B is not aware that something has changed.

How can I trigger a stack deployment when another stack has been created? `addDependency` is not what I am looking for. I'm searching form something like `addpostdependency()`.

```js
    const apiKeyParam = new ssm.StringParameter(this, 'ApiKeyIdParam', {
            parameterName: constantsConfiguration.APPSYNC_GRAPGHQL_API_KEY,
            stringValue: this.apiGrapghQL.apiKey ? this.apiGrapghQL.apiKey : "ApiKey",
            description: 'this param for the AutBus GraphQL Api keyId',
            type: ssm.ParameterType.STRING,
            tier: ssm.ParameterTier.STANDARD,
            allowedPattern: '.*',
        });
```

After I put the new value in the Parameterstore I would like to notify the other stack to redeploy.

Comment: How does Stack B consume the parameter value from Stack A?  As a Lambda env var?  `CfnParameter`?

Comment: @fedonev exactly, I get the wanted parameter store value through CDK with the function valueFromLookup and give it to the lambda as env variable.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and least fragile solution is to remove the environment variable.  Instead, have your Lambda fetch the parameter value from the Parameter Store on each invocation. Call the SDK's [GetParameterCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-ssm/classes/getparametercommand.html)<sup>*</sup>.  The Lambda is guaranteed to have the latest value.

Your other options are complex and error-prone.  You could add a Custom Resource to Stack A to update Stack B's Lambda configuration on each update.  Or you could listen to parameter change events emitted by EventBridge to trigger a Lambda update.  Yuck.

Note that "triggering a stack deployment" in CloudFormation *won't* work here.  You are setting the env var with the CDK `StringParameter.valueFromLookup` [context method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/context.html#context_methods).  This method makes a synth-time call to the Parameter Store and caches the value locally. It sets the CloudFormation template's env var value as this synth-time *string literal*, not as a `Ref` to Stack A's parameter. No amount of redeploying Stack B in CloudFormation will change this.

* Alternatively, consider the new [AWS Parameters and Secrets Lambda Extension](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ps-integration-lambda-extensions.html). Your function fetches the parameter values from a cached `http://localhost` endpoint in a Lambda layer, instead of making a SDK request each time.